# Deal in vs deal with

Tags: phrases, verbs

I wrote this sentence: "The scientists dealing in complex systems have proposed...." But then I thought 'dealing with' would be correct. Are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can *deal in* or *deal with*. When one is talking about scientists, the difference is fuzzy.

[*Deal in*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/To+deal+in) is defined as *to have to do **with***; to be engaged in; to practice; as, they deal in political matters.

[*Deal with*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/To+deal+with) is defined as *to treat in any manner; to use, whether well or ill*; ***to have to do with***.

> Addressing a meeting of the Society for Conservation Biology (SCB) in San Jose, California, last week, he tried to convince the crowd that they have a responsibility to be not just scientists [dealing in](http://cstpr.colorado.edu/prometheus/archives/the_honest_broker/000871the_honest_broker_c.html) objective facts, but also advocates pushing particular policies. -colorado.edu
>
> These philosophies, she maintains, do not provide appropriate guidance for biologists and other scientists [dealing with](http://bioscience.oxfordjournals.org/content/61/3/241.full) complex situations and systems. - Oxford Jounals

As a one time scientist, I think either is acceptable, with *dealing with* perhaps being the more common.

Comment: Once a scientist, ...

Answer (score 2):

Deal with means there is a struggle or counter no matter how small it is.  You might need to deal with a contemptuous father-in-law.  You might need to deal with a scratch on your shin.

Deal in means that you interact with something, it's part of your trade, or you actually trade it.  I deal in strawberries, meaning I buy and/or sell strawberries.

In your case you are conveying a small struggle that the scientists need to deal with.

Comment: That's an interesting distinction. I meant the scientists whose main field of research is complex systems. I didn't want to imply any struggle. So I guess 'deal in' is fine. But, then, it's not their trade (in the commercial sense). It's still OK?

Comment: It depends if the sentence is more about their profession or their day to day.

Comment: Wiktionary adds the non-struggle senses for 'deal with', Erik: To handle verbally or in some form of artistic expression; to address or discuss as a subject; To take action with respect to (someone or something); To consider, as an example; To come to terms with; to overcome any difficulties presented by; To be in charge of, act on, or dispose of; To ...

Answer (score 2):

*Deal in* means to engage in an activity or business. For example, he deals in clothes or cars. 
*Deal with* means to tackle a situation or a challenge. The miners have a lot of difficulties to deal with. The teacher threatens to deal with any student who misbehaves.